# Return successively different values for a symbol `with-redefs` (Clojure)

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I am hoping to use `with-redefs` to mock user input from STDIN.

First, I am testing incorrect input, which should re-ask the user for input. Then, the correct input should be given.

Is there a way to use `with-redefs` to bind successively different values to a given symbol?

I'm trying to get this functionality:

```
(with-redefs [read-line (fn [] "HI")
              read-line (fn [] "OK")]
  (do (println (read-line)) ;; -> "HI"
      (println (read-line)))) ;; -> "OK"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not specifically, but you could always 'let-over-lambda' with some state!

```
(let [a (atom ["a" "b"])]
  (defn f []
    (let [r (first @a)]
      (swap! a rest)
      r)))

(f) ;; "a"
(f) ;; "b"
(f) ;; nil
```

In your particular case, it would make sense to have a function that generates the 'stateful' function, So a full example would be:

```
(defn maker [l]
  (let [a (atom l)]
    (fn []
      (let [r (first @a)]
        (swap! a rest)
        r))))

(with-redefs [read-line (maker ["HI" "OK"])]
  (do (println (read-line)) ;; -> "HI"
      (println (read-line)))) ;; -> "OK"
```

Comment: Very interesting. Never thought about a state-maker. Thanks for opening my mind!

Answer (score 4):

You will probably be happier using `with-in-str` for this purpose:

```
  (with-in-str "Hello"
    (println (read-line)))
  (with-in-str "There"
    (println (read-line))))
```

with result:

```
(read-line) => "Hello"
(read-line) => "There"
```

Be sure to always have a browser tab open to [The Clojure Cheatsheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) and peruse it often!

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty simple. The only thing is that my read-lines are being called from some function down the line, so I can't wrap them individually in the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample that could be useful I believe:

```
(ns project.test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]))

(deftest test-user-input

  (testing "wrong input"
    (with-in-str "some wrong input"
      (is (thrown?
           SomeExceptionClass
           (call-your-function)))))

  (testing "correct input"
    (with-in-str "some correct input"
      (let [result (call-your-function)]
        (is (= result [:proper :data]))))))
```